# Where is build.yaml file in Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, yaml, dart-build

I am looking for a `build.yaml` file in the flutter project, but I can't find it.
Is there any way I can edit this file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The file is only there if you create it.
It should be in the same directory as the `pubspec.yaml` file.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/build_yaml_format.md

Comment: I have flutter project (Mobile application not web), and there is no build.yaml, any idea where can be found or need to create? want to exclude some files any way?

Comment: You need to create it. See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Code-generation-in-Flutter. What are you trying to accomplish? `build.yaml` is for code generation, not for Dart-to-binary compilation.

Comment: Okay I have created one, want to exclude some file I'm trying using this https://pub.dev/packages/build_config#-readme-tab-

Comment: is it possible?